Problema con el emulador de android studio; Mensaje sobre un botón
Estoy empezando en android studio. He creado un botón con el texto "SaludApp", pero al ejecutar el emulador el nombre "AndroidMaster" cubre el botón, se coloca encima... ¿A qué se puede deber el problema?





Creeria que es por el enableEdgeToEdge que tienes  en tu oncreate()

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
